# How to sort a dataframe in the same order as a sorted plot with seqIplot function?

Tags: dataframe, sorting, traminer

I'm using seqIplot function (TraMineR) to create a sorted sequence index plot (sortv = "from.end"). How can I get the dataframe sorted in the same order ?
Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

The TraMineRextras package has functions `sorti` and `sortv` that respectively return the sort index and the sort variable. To sorting the data, you need the `sorti` variable.

Here is an example using the `actcal` data.

```
library(TraMineRextras)

# actcal data set
data(actcal)
# using only sequence 11 to 20
actcal.seq <- seqdef(actcal[11:20,13:24])
sort.index <- sorti(actcal.seq, start="beg")
actcal.seq[sort.index,]

# 2103 A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A
# 528  A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A
# 4866 B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B
# 5108 B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B
# 5386 B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B
# 3876 B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B
# 5238 B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-C
# 3972 C-C-C-C-C-C-C-C-C-B-B-B
# 4977 C-C-C-C-C-C-C-C-C-C-C-C
# 6175 D-D-D-D-D-D-D-D-D-D-D-D
```

With `start="beg"`, you get the order corresponding to the `sortv="from.start"` argument of the plot function, and with `start="end"` the order corresponding to `"from.end"`.

You can similarly use the `sort.index` with any table where rows match with sequences as `actcal[11:20,]` in the example above.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit unclear which data frame you are alluding to, but I assume you are talking about your sequence data.

The sorting is done in a two-step procedure:

1. Create a sort index using `order`
2. sort data using this index

Below you find an example drawing on `{TraMineR}`'s example data `actcal`.

```r
> library(TraMineR)
> 
> # actcal data set
> data(actcal)
> 
> # We use only a sample of 10 cases
> set.seed(1)
> actcal <- actcal[sample(nrow(actcal),10),]
> actcal.seq <- seqdef(actcal,13:24)
 [>] 4 distinct states appear in the data: 
     1 = A
     2 = B
     3 = C
     4 = D
 [>] state coding:
       [alphabet]  [label]  [long label] 
     1  A           A        A
     2  B           B        B
     3  C           C        C
     4  D           D        D
 [>] 10 sequences in the data set
 [>] min/max sequence length: 12/12
> 
> # here the sorting happens: 
> #     1) we create a sorting index with order
> #     2) we sort the data according to the index
> x <- as.data.frame(actcal.seq)
> sortvar <- do.call(order, x[,ncol(x):1])
> sorted.data <- actcal.seq[sortvar,]
> 
> # bonus: change rownumber to index position 
> # to ease comparison with seqplot output
> rownames(sorted.data) <- 1:nrow(sorted.data)
> 
> #Inspect data
> #unsorted data
> actcal.seq
     Sequence               
3649 A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A
6274 D-D-D-D-D-D-D-D-D-D-D-D
4130 C-C-C-C-C-C-C-C-C-C-C-C
3236 B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B
2302 B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B
2172 A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A
5671 D-D-D-D-D-C-C-C-C-D-D-D
4039 B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B
153  D-D-D-D-D-D-D-D-D-D-D-D
5712 B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B
> #sorted data
> sorted.data
   Sequence               
1  A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A
2  A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A
3  B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B
4  B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B
5  B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B
6  B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B
7  C-C-C-C-C-C-C-C-C-C-C-C
8  D-D-D-D-D-C-C-C-C-D-D-D
9  D-D-D-D-D-D-D-D-D-D-D-D
10 D-D-D-D-D-D-D-D-D-D-D-D
> 
> #Compare to plot output
> seqiplot(actcal.seq, sortv = "from.end")
```

[image]